# Zip4j behavior in multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading, zip4j

I am looking for an information on zip4j behavior in multithreaded environment.

1. How does zip4j work in multithreaded environment ?
2. Does it use JVM's OS to complete process ?
3. and how many process are involved in zip file creation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: Java has been a "multithreaded environment" from day one, so your first question basically is just, "how does zip4j work?" I'm voting to close because that's too broad for this site. This site really is meant to help developers get past specific problems, ("I'm trying to do X, but I can't get past this one step...") The questions that get the most positive attention are then ones you ask about _your own_ code. ("I wrote this function `<actual code shown>`. When I call it, it does this ... But, I was expecting it to do ... instead. What did I do wrong?")

Comment: P.S., If you were trying to learn how zip4j works by [reading its source code](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j), and you encountered something that the author did that you don't understand, then that could be a good question for this site.